# Why isn't docker populating /etc/hosts

Tags: networking, docker

I've got two docker containers on a host. Both live in a default `bridge` network, but are attached to a user defined `monitoring` network after startup.

I can see that it's successful via `docker inspect ...`:

One has (abbreviated):

```
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    ...
                },
                "monitoring": {
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "certmon.web",
                        "93a4010aca97.certmon.web",
                        "93a4010aca97"
                    ],
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    ...
                }
            }
```

The other has:

```
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
                    ...
                },
                "monitoring": {
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "influxdb.web",
                        "32c95fdebbd9.influxdb.web",
                        "32c95fdebbd9"
                    ],
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.3",
                    ...
                }
            }
```

I expect the aliases defined in the `monitoring` network to get automagically injected into `/etc/hosts` in each container - but that's not happening.

Connections via IP "just work", so it's definitely the same network / both containers are correctly attached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't those aliases DNS aliases?  If you try to ping influxdb.web from certmon.web, does it succeed?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille True, it is resolved by DNS rather than `/etc/hosts`. It's totally not what I expected.

Comment: I find it hard to find information about monitoring aliases, DNS aliases was all I found.  I'll put it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't seem to resolve hostnames via files, it has it own DNS built in to allow the containers to find each other.

You're not doing anything wrong (that one can see ;-) ).